# SonarQube doesn't work with Intellij Community 2019.2

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

I'm using SonarLint 4.1.1.3345 with IntelliJ Community 2019.2 version by binding project to our SonarQube (with SonarJava 5.3 (build 13828)installed) server. However, I got error with below stack trace from SonarLint log:

```
Java Main Files AST scan
60 source files to be analyzed
Unable to create symbol table for : C:\Users\username\SomeFile.java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:148)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:136)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.BytecodeCompleter.loadClass(BytecodeCompleter.java:204)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.Symbols.<init>(Symbols.java:176)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.SemanticModel.createFor(SemanticModel.java:59)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:110)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:96)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:68)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:116)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:110)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:93)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.analyzer.sensor.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:81)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.analyzer.sensor.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:72)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.analysis.AnalysisContainer.doAfterStart(AnalysisContainer.java:132)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:125)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:110)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.storage.StorageAnalyzer.analyze(StorageAnalyzer.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.storage.StorageContainerHandler.analyze(StorageContainerHandler.java:82)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.lambda$analyze$0(ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.java:152)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.withReadLock(ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.java:344)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.withReadLock(ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.java:334)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.analyze(ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.java:149)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.core.ConnectedSonarLintFacade.analyze(ConnectedSonarLintFacade.java:74)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.core.SonarLintFacade.startAnalysis(SonarLintFacade.java:63)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.analysis.SonarLintAnalyzer.analyzeModule(SonarLintAnalyzer.java:97)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.analysis.SonarLintTask.analyze(SonarLintTask.java:176)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.analysis.SonarLintTask.run(SonarLintTask.java:100)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.analysis.SonarLintUserTask.run(SonarLintUserTask.java:39)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.analysis.SonarLintJobManager.lambda$runTask$1(SonarLintJobManager.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:169)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:591)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:537)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:156)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.analysis.SonarLintJobManager.lambda$runTask$2(SonarLintJobManager.java:120)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

"Unsupported class file major version 55" tells me that the class file Sonar used for code analysis is for java 11 version whereas my class was compiled with java 7 (I took the same class and ran it with javap it showed major version 51), and I don't even have java 11 installed on my system.

Because it works for my teammates. The only difference is they have lower version of IntelliJ installed. So I downloaded IntelliJ 2019.1.4 and it started working.

Could someone explain why it doesn't work with later version of IntelliJ and why the above error occurred? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation about classloaders in the IDE/sonarlint/plugin:

https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarlint-analysis-fails-on-intellij-2019-2-with-java-11-runtime/12905/3

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-3056

> **Example with SonarLint**
>
> In SonarLint IntelliJ running environment, this is more or less the
>   classpath hierarchy:
>
> JDK -> IntelliJ classes -> SonarLint (+deps) [child-first] -> Java
>   plugin (+packaged deps) [child-first] -> Squid [parent-first]. So
>   imagine we analyze a class that is using a class X. If IntelliJ's
>   classloader happens to also use class X (same fully qualified name),
>   this will be used instead of the X provided in the analysis classpath,
>   even if they are to different copies of the class (different versions,
>   for example).

Comment: Thanks @devwebcl, I have one follow up question: when I don't bind the project to remote SonarQube server, i.e. scan by the rules defined in Rules tab of SonarLint, everything works fine. Why? I thought connecting to SonarQube server mode means use the rules/profiles defined on the server. Also I tried to delete target folder, the local scan still work, so does it actually compile the java files on the fly?How does it work in each mode? I tried to find a documentation that explains the different mode, but I wasn't able to. Could you please provide a link if you know of any?Thank you very much!

Comment: The only knowledge repo is on the ticket https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-3056 it looks is a known bug, but they don't have a solution yet.